# How to use with routes in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I create 2 route (`web.php` and `admin.php`) in Laravel 5.6.

`RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    $this->mapAdminRoutes();
}

protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}

protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware(['web', 'adminInformation'])
        ->prefix('manage')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
}
```

Now i need get just controller names in `admin.php`.

For example:

```
$r = \Route::getRoutes();
    foreach ($r as $value) {

        echo($value->getName() . "<br />");
    }
```

Method `Route::getRoutes()` show all routes (web.php & admin.php).

How to get name controller just from `admin.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can filter by **prefix**:

```
$routerCollection = \Route::getRoutes();
foreach ($routerCollection as $route) {
    if ($route->getPrefix() == 'manage') {
        echo($value->getName() . "<br />");
    }
}
```